# Vapor deposition of 5um Beryllium onto 0.5um mylar

Tags: materials, design

I am searching for a service that allows the deposition of 5 micron thick Beryillium onto half micron thick mylar for a R&D project I am doing.

I am having a difficult time finding such a service through google.
Is this possible to do? I have seen some services that offer it up to 2 microns of Beryllium but not 5 microns.
Can anyone head me in the right direction? I would be greatly appreciative :)

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here

Comment: can you have them make multiple passes of the <2um process to get your total thickness?

Comment: there's also Thomas register, though that's a bit dated. You could call around universities with microfab facilities for MEMS, they often have core labs that can run processes related to this, especially if it's small.

Comment: You DO NOT WANT TO DO THIS. Beryllium is absolutely fatal in PPB quantities if atomized or pulverized. Handling this with a small cut on your hand would probably kill you. It's a bit less problematic as a metal casting. It can be machined under full negative pressure cleanroom conditions - by suited machinists or robots.

Comment: I thought it was the oxide that is toxic?